# How to build static zeromq under ndk for android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, zeromq

I try to build zmq for android follow http://www.zeromq.org/build:android
but it do not work, link error for some reason i do not know.

I google it a lot and I find no way to make it right.

so I give up to build it in official way and I finally build it by writing my own Android.mk,
my OS is OSX 10.8.3, and ndk is r8e, zeromq is 3.2.2

.1. I copy the hello-jni folder under android-ndk-r8e/samples/ and rename it to hello-zmq. 
.2. copy all the files under zeromq-3.2.2/src to hello-zmq/jni
.3. modify platform.hpp like (if no platform.hpp there, make it under hello-zmq/jni):

> ```
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <alloca.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_ALLOCA_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <arpa/inet.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_ARPA_INET_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the `clock_gettime' function. */
> /* #undef HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME */
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <dlfcn.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <errno.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_ERRNO_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the `freeifaddrs' function. */
> #define HAVE_FREEIFADDRS 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the `gethrtime' function. */
> /* #undef HAVE_GETHRTIME */
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the `getifaddrs' function. */
> #define HAVE_GETIFADDRS 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the `gettimeofday' function. */
> #define HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <ifaddrs.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_IFADDRS_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <inttypes.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the `iphlpapi' library (-liphlpapi). */
> /* #undef HAVE_LIBIPHLPAPI */
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the `nsl' library (-lnsl). */
> /* #undef HAVE_LIBNSL */
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the `pthread' library (-lpthread). */
> #define HAVE_LIBPTHREAD 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the `rpcrt4' library (-lrpcrt4). */
> /* #undef HAVE_LIBRPCRT4 */
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the `rt' library (-lrt). */
> /* #undef HAVE_LIBRT */
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the `socket' library (-lsocket). */
> /* #undef HAVE_LIBSOCKET */
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the `ws2_32' library (-lws2_32). */
> /* #undef HAVE_LIBWS2_32 */
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <limits.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_LIMITS_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <memory.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the `memset' function. */
> #define HAVE_MEMSET 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <netinet/in.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_NETINET_IN_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <netinet/tcp.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_NETINET_TCP_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the `perror' function. */
> #define HAVE_PERROR 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the `socket' function. */
> #define HAVE_SOCKET 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if stdbool.h conforms to C99. */
> #define HAVE_STDBOOL_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <stddef.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_STDDEF_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <stdint.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <stdlib.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <strings.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <string.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <sys/eventfd.h> header file. */
> /* #undef HAVE_SYS_EVENTFD_H */
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <sys/socket.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_SYS_SOCKET_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <sys/stat.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <sys/time.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_SYS_TIME_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <sys/types.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <sys/uio.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_SYS_UIO_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <time.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_TIME_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <unistd.h> header file. */
> #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the <windows.h> header file. */
> /* #undef HAVE_WINDOWS_H */
>
> /* Define to 1 if the system has the type `_Bool'. */
> /* #undef HAVE__BOOL */
>
> /* Define to the sub-directory in which libtool stores uninstalled libraries.
>  */
> #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
>
> /* Define to 1 if your C compiler doesn't accept -c and -o together. */
> /* #undef NO_MINUS_C_MINUS_O */
>
> /* Name of package */
> #define PACKAGE "zeromq"
>
> /* Define to the address where bug reports for this package should be sent. */
> #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "zeromq-dev@lists.zeromq.org"
>
> /* Define to the full name of this package. */
> #define PACKAGE_NAME "zeromq"
>
> /* Define to the full name and version of this package. */
> #define PACKAGE_STRING "zeromq 3.2.2"
>
> /* Define to the one symbol short name of this package. */
> #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "zeromq"
>
> /* Define to the home page for this package. */
> #define PACKAGE_URL ""
>
> /* Define to the version of this package. */
> #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.2.2"
>
> /* Define as the return type of signal handlers (`int' or `void'). */
> #define RETSIGTYPE void
>
> /* Define to 1 if you have the ANSI C header files. */
> #define STDC_HEADERS 1
>
> /* Define to 1 if you can safely include both <sys/time.h> and <time.h>. */
> #define TIME_WITH_SYS_TIME 1
>
> /* Version number of package */
> #define VERSION "3.2.2"
>
> /* Force to use mutexes */
> /* #undef ZMQ_FORCE_MUTEXES */
>
> /* Have AIX OS */
> /* #undef ZMQ_HAVE_AIX */
>
> /* Have Android OS */
> #define ZMQ_HAVE_ANDROID 1
>
> /* Have Cygwin */
> /* #undef ZMQ_HAVE_CYGWIN */
>
> /* Have eventfd extension. */
> //#define ZMQ_HAVE_EVENTFD 1
>
> /* Have FreeBSD OS */
> /* #undef ZMQ_HAVE_FREEBSD */
>
> /* Have HPUX OS */
> /* #undef ZMQ_HAVE_HPUX */
>
> /* Have ifaddrs.h header. */
> //#define ZMQ_HAVE_IFADDRS 1
>
> /* Have Linux OS */
> #define ZMQ_HAVE_LINUX 1
>
> /* Have MinGW32 */
> /* #undef ZMQ_HAVE_MINGW32 */
>
> /* Have NetBSD OS */
> /* #undef ZMQ_HAVE_NETBSD */
>
> /* Have OpenBSD OS */
> /* #undef ZMQ_HAVE_OPENBSD */
>
> /* Have OpenPGM extension */
> /* #undef ZMQ_HAVE_OPENPGM */
>
> /* Have DarwinOSX OS */
> //#define ZMQ_HAVE_OSX 1
>
> /* Have QNX Neutrino OS */
> /* #undef ZMQ_HAVE_QNXNTO */
>
> /* Whether SOCK_CLOEXEC is defined and functioning. */
> /* #undef ZMQ_HAVE_SOCK_CLOEXEC */
>
> /* Have Solaris OS */
> /* #undef ZMQ_HAVE_SOLARIS */
>
> /* Whether SO_KEEPALIVE is supported. */
> //#define ZMQ_HAVE_SO_KEEPALIVE 1
>
> /* Whether TCP_KEEPALIVE is supported. */
> //#define ZMQ_HAVE_TCP_KEEPALIVE 1
>
> /* Whether TCP_KEEPCNT is supported. */
> /* #undef ZMQ_HAVE_TCP_KEEPCNT */
>
> /* Whether TCP_KEEPIDLE is supported. */
> /* #undef ZMQ_HAVE_TCP_KEEPIDLE */
>
> /* Whether TCP_KEEPINTVL is supported. */
> /* #undef ZMQ_HAVE_TCP_KEEPINTVL */
>
> /* Have uio.h header. */
> #define ZMQ_HAVE_UIO 1
>
> /* Have Windows OS */
> /* #undef ZMQ_HAVE_WINDOWS */
>
> /* Define for Solaris 2.5.1 so the uint32_t typedef from <sys/synch.h>,
>  <pthread.h>, or <semaphore.h> is not used. If the typedef were allowed, the
>  #define below would cause a syntax error. */
> /* #undef _UINT32_T */
>
> /* Define to empty if `const' does not conform to ANSI C. */
> /* #undef const */
>
> /* Define to `__inline__' or `__inline' if that's what the C compiler
>  calls it, or to nothing if 'inline' is not supported under any name.  */
> #ifndef __cplusplus
> /* #undef inline */
> #endif
>
> /* Define to `unsigned int' if <sys/types.h> does not define. */
> /* #undef size_t */
>
> /* Define to `int' if <sys/types.h> does not define. */
> /* #undef ssize_t */
>
> /* Define to the type of an unsigned integer type of width exactly 32 bits if
>  such a type exists and the standard includes do not define it. */
> /* #undef uint32_t */
>
> /* Define to empty if the keyword `volatile' does not work. Warning: valid
>  code using `volatile' can become incorrect without. Disable with care. */
> /* #undef volatile */
> ```

.4. then write a Android.mk file under hello-zmq/jni like:

> ```
> LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
>
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>
> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES  := $(LOCAL_PATH) \
>   /opt/android-toolchain/sysroot/usr/include \
>
>
> LOCAL_MODULE := zeromq
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := address.cpp \
>   clock.cpp \
>   ctx.cpp \
>   dealer.cpp \
>   decoder.cpp \
>   devpoll.cpp \
>   dist.cpp \
>   encoder.cpp \
>   epoll.cpp \
>   err.cpp \
>   fq.cpp \
>   io_object.cpp \
>   io_thread.cpp \
>   ip.cpp \
>   ipc_address.cpp \
>   ipc_connecter.cpp \
>   ipc_listener.cpp \
>   kqueue.cpp \
>   lb.cpp \
>   mailbox.cpp \
>   msg.cpp \
>   mtrie.cpp \
>   object.cpp \
>   options.cpp \
>   own.cpp \
>   pair.cpp \
>   pgm_receiver.cpp \
>   pgm_sender.cpp \
>   pgm_socket.cpp \
>   pipe.cpp \
>   poll.cpp \
>   poller_base.cpp \
>   precompiled.cpp \
>   proxy.cpp \
>   pub.cpp \
>   pull.cpp \
>   push.cpp \
>   random.cpp \
>   reaper.cpp \
>   rep.cpp \
>   req.cpp \
>   router.cpp \
>   select.cpp \
>   session_base.cpp \
>   signaler.cpp \
>   socket_base.cpp \
>   stream_engine.cpp \
>   sub.cpp \
>   tcp.cpp \
>   tcp_address.cpp \
>   tcp_connecter.cpp \
>   tcp_listener.cpp \
>   thread.cpp \
>   trie.cpp \
>   v1_decoder.cpp \
>   v1_encoder.cpp \
>   xpub.cpp \
>   xsub.cpp \
>   zmq.cpp \
>   zmq_utils.cpp
>
> LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -DZMQ_FORCE_POLL -fPIC
>
> include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
>
>
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
> LOCAL_MODULE := zeromq-jni
> LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := zeromq
>
> include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
> ```

.5. write a Application.mk under hello-zmq/jni:

> APP_STL := gnustl_static

.6. make sure you have follow the http://www.zeromq.org/build:android 's General Prerequisites make-standalone-toolchain part.

.7. use ./ndk-build under hello-zmq/jni folder and a static library libzeromq.a will usable.

I have test for android device and it is just work fine.

I am still looking for a official way to build zeromq for android...

Comment: Trying to create an assembly zmqLib for android (xamarin monodroid). Faced with this problem. Can you explain step 6 more detail? Or suggest any other solution. Thanks!